# ASP.NET MVC - Pass model value to data annotation parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, data-annotations

I want to pass a value from one of my properties in my model to my data annotation to validate my password property, but I have no idea how I can achieve this. When I am doing this at this way I get the following error:

```
an attribute argument must be a constant expression typeof expression or array
```

My model:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Voornaam { get; set; }
    public string Achternaam { get; set; }
    public string Gebruikersnaam { get; set; }

    [Password(AttributeVoornaam = this.Voornaam, AttributeAchternaam = this.Achternaam, AttributeGebruikersnaam = this.Gebruikersnaam)]
    public string Wachtwoord { get; set; }
}
```

And in my data annotation I am doing this:

```
public class PasswordAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string AttributeVoornaam { get; set; }
    public string AttributeAchternaam { get; set; }
    public string AttributeGebruikersnaam { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string strValue = value.ToString();

        if (strValue.Contains(AttributeVoornaam.ToLower()) || strValue.Contains(AttributeAchternaam.ToLower()) ||
               strValue.Contains(AttributeGebruikersnaam.ToLower()))
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Uw wachtwoord mag niet uw voornaam, achternaam of gebruikersnaam bevatten.";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't pass variable values (values that are not evaluated at compile-time) into attributes. They have to be literal values or constant values.

What you *can* pass into attributes, though, are the names of the properties of your model that you want to evaluate at run-time, and then have your `IsValid` method evaluate these values at run-time by accessing the `ValidationContext` in the override that returns a `ValidationResult` of `ValidationAttribute`.

Or, if you are always evaluating these same properties, then you can just grab the reference to your model, and use that directly:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    LoginModel loginModel = (LoginModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

    string strValue = value.ToString();

    if (strValue.Contains(loginModel.Voornaam.ToLower()) || 
        strValue.Contains(loginModel.Achternaam.ToLower()) ||             
        strValue.Contains(loginModel.Gebruikersnaam.ToLower()))
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Uw wachtwoord mag niet uw voornaam, achternaam of gebruikersnaam bevatten.";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked fine for me for some minor tweaks, thanks!

Comment: Why do you return boolean values instead of `ValidationResult`s?

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible, because the attributes, including their data, are placed into the metadata of the assembly at compile-time. See [Attribute parameter types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664615%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Instead you can pass a name of the dependent property as a string. I will show you a sample with one property and you will add others the same way:

```
public class PasswordAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public PasswordAttribute(string voornaamPropertyName)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(voornaamPropertyName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("voornaamPropertyName");

        VoornaamPropertyName = voornaamPropertyName;
    }

    public string VoornaamPropertyName { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        PropertyInfo voornaamPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(VoornaamPropertyName);
        if (voornaamPropertyInfo == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Could not find a property named {0}", VoornaamPropertyName));
        }

        var voornaamProperty = voornaamPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance); // here you have the value of the property

       ...
    }
}
```

Then

```
[Password("Voornaam")]
public string Wachtwoord { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't pass the variable values into attributes. You could add custom validation rule to your model:

```
public class LoginModel: IValidatableObject
{
    public string Voornaam {get;set;}
    public string Achternaam {get;set;}
    public string Gebruikersnaam {get;set;}

    public string Wachtwoord { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        var pwd = this.Wachtwoord.ToLower();
        if(pwd.Contains(this.Voornaam.ToLower()) || pwd.Contains(this.Achternaam.ToLower()) || pwd.Contains(this.Gebruikersnaam.ToLower())){
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("Uw wachtwoord mag niet uw voornaam, achternaam of gebruikersnaam bevatten."));
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

You could also change it into multiple if statements and add seperate ValidationResults (one for Voornaam, one for Achternaam and one for Gebruikersnaam).