# How to change PasswordValidator Properties error message in asp.net mvc identity 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

I have the following register action result post that automatically written by identity 2:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
                ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;
                return View("DisplayEmail");
            }
            //My problem is here
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

in above code(where I mark by comment) if something go wrong it will show me a specified error in English by `AddError(Result);` Method. `Result` type is `IdentityResult`.

this is `AddError(Result);` method:

```
private void AddErrors(IdentityResult error)
    {
        foreach (var Error in error.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", Error);
        }
    }
```

I've search a lot but I just find error customization for `Required` and `StringLength`

[image]

**my question:** How can I change all this error message to language I want?

I'm so new in MVC; thanks for your easy solutions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801718/adding-custom-error-message-for-model-property

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801718/adding-custom-error-message-for-model-property

Comment: my question is how can I custom password error, not null required error!

Comment: Best way to do it by creating a resource file for your desired language.